# JSF custom component requestmap value null for children

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a component that I created to access a generic object that is being cast to another type based on a number. I use a "var" attribute in the request map to allow the children within my component to have access to the object. When trying to access the object named by "var" in a child component I get the following exception:
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'objectName' resolved to null.

Here is my component code and the markup:

```
@FacesComponent(value = "components.AgendaItemTextAccessor", createTag = true)
public class AgendaItemTextAccessor  extends UIComponentBase{
public String getVar(){
    return (String) getStateHelper().eval("var");
}
public void setVar(String var){
    getStateHelper().put("var", var);
}
public AgendaItemText getValue(){
    return (AgendaItemText) getStateHelper().eval("value");
}
public void setValue(AgendaItemObject text){
    getStateHelper().put("value", text);
}

@Override
public boolean getRendersChildren() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void encodeChildren(FacesContext context) throws IOException{
    if ((context == null)){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    AgendaItemText text = (AgendaItemText)getValue();
    String varname = getVar();
    Map<String, Object> requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestMap();

    Object varStore = requestMap.get(varname); // in case this Object already exists in the requestMap,
                                        // emulate "scoped behavior" by storing the value and
                                        // restoring it after all rendering is done.

    if(text != null){
        requestMap.put(varname, text);
        for(UIComponent child: getChildren()){
            child.encodeAll(context);
        }         
        // restore the original value
        if(varStore != null){
            requestMap.put(varname, varStore);
        }else{
            requestMap.remove(varname);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String getFamily() {
    return "components.AgendaItemTextAccessor";
}
```

Markup

```
<xx:agendaItemTextAccessor value="#{itemValue}" var="itemVar">
    <p:inputText value="#{itemVar.text}">
        <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{Controller.printMe(itemVar)}" />
    </p:inputText>
</xx:agendaItemTextAccessor>
```

Comment: There is a collection of abstract objects being used and four implementing classes. In the view different things are rendered based on what the implemented class is. We were instructed to create a component that takes in the abstract object and cast it base on a field that defines its type. So the value that is assigned is the object from the collection that is abstract, and the var is the name of the variable that has been cast and made available to the child components. The markup I provided is just a example.

Comment: I see your point, I guess it was assumed that since you have to cast it in the back-end it would have to be cast in the front-end as well. I'll bring this up later. For the sake of this question being helpful to others, why does the variable resolve to null?

Comment: I reposted it as an answer.

Comment: Accepted the answer, thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *We were instructed to create a component that takes in the abstract object and cast it base on a field that defines its type*

You're going in the wrong direction as to achieving the functional requirement. The `var` adds unnecessary complexity. Just use `#{itemValue}` directly. In EL, everything is `Object` anyway (reflection, you know), so absolutely no need to cast up, down, left or right before putting it back in EL.

```
<p:inputText value="#{itemValue.text}">
    <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{controller.printMe(itemValue)}" />
</p:inputText>
```

---

As to the concrete problem, you faced it because you only set it during `encodeChildren()` and not during `processDecodes()`, `processValidators()`, `processUpdates()` and `broadcast()`. In other words, it's only available during render response phase, not during all other phases where it may be relevant. You unfortunately didn't show the full stack trace anywhere, but it should point out which phase is guilty (my educated guess says `processValidators()`). Normally, `var` is only implemented in repeater or output-only components. Peek in the [source code of](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/master/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/facelets/component/UIRepeat.java) `<ui:repeat>` how to do it right (and peek in [source code](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/component/tree/Tree.java) of [`<o:tree>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/tree) how to do it the DRY way).